# Why I always get messgage "clause and contains nonaggregated column" when running a query in codeigniter?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to sum the revenue based on the channel and product name column, here is the query that I use in Codeigniter:

```
$datas['row']=$this->db->query('SELECT channel,product_name, SUM(revenue) AS revenue FROM contribution WHERE YEAR(date) = 2019 GROUP BY channel, SUBSTRING(product_name, 1, 3)')->result();
```

But the result is always return this message: "Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'datamart.contribution.product_name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

but if I change the query into this:

```
$datas['row']=$this->db->query('SELECT channel,product_name, SUM(revenue) AS revenue FROM contribution WHERE YEAR(date) = 2019 GROUP BY channel, product_name')->result();
```

it return value successfully but not what I want. It return the sum of revenue that only grouped by the channel not the product_name. I want the sum of revenue based on the channel and also the product name.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot select `product` if you are aggregating by only a substring.  You need one of:

```
SELECT channel, MIN(product_name) as product_name, SUM(revenue) AS revenue
FROM contribution
WHERE YEAR(date) = 2019
GROUP BY channel, SUBSTRING(product_name, 1, 3);
```

Or:

```
SELECT channel, SUBSTRING(product_name, 1, 3) as product_name_3, SUM(revenue) AS revenue
FROM contribution
WHERE YEAR(date) = 2019
GROUP BY channel, SUBSTRING(product_name, 1, 3);
```

It is unclear which you really want.

Also, I would suggest that you rewrite the `WHERE` clause to:

```
WHERE date >= '2019-01-01' AND date < '2020-01-01'
```

This makes it easier for the optimizer to use indexes and partitions.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, the first one is works for me